# Does ruby have getlocale method?

Tags: ruby

I need to detect language in Ruby without any rubygems installed. Both Python and Perl do have locale utilities as part of the core API. I want something like

```
# LC_ALL=cs_CZ ruby test.rb
Your language is: cs_CZ
Your currency is: CZK
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no core library for doing what you need to do, but there is a Rubygem that seems to do what you need. https://github.com/mutoh/locale

Answer (score 5):

Rails Internationalization http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

```
I18n.locale
```

Also, check your application.rb file if you want to set defaults like so:

```
I18n.default_locale = [:en]
I18n.available_locales = [:en, :fr]
```

If you don't have access to ANY gems, including Rails, take a look at how svenfuchs implemented it: https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n

Quick question though: you do know you could vendor gems and use them without access to rubygems right?

Answer (score 1):

Does `ENV["LANG"]` work for you?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: ENV["LANG"] holds the language of the current locale, dont see why this is not a valid answer.

Comment: `ENV["LANG"]` is nil with my test (ruby 1.9, Win7)

Comment: Python and Perl also dont do more than returning environment variables. For Windows you would probably have to to something like "sysinfo" to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As this question is about Ruby and not about Ruby on Rails, my need as well, here's something outside Rails:

Installing rubygem 'locale' (documented [here](https://github.com/mutoh/locale)):

```
$ gem install locale
```

Using it:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'locale'

Locale.current = 'whateverlocaleyouwant'
```

There doesn't seem to be such functionality in core Ruby.